# IndentationError In Python Script

Tags: python

So I'm making a text adventure game. When I run the code, it says "`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level on line 24 elif response == "right": ^ in main.py`"

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?
This is the code:

````
import os

# Variables
directions = ["left", "right", "forward", "backward"]

# Name
name = raw_input("What is your name, camper? ")
os.system("clear")

# Story Introduction
print ("""
It's the last night of RV camping with your family in the big forest.
Your family has decided to go on a walk to see the nice stars in the night sky.
As you follow your family, you drop your flashlight in the bushes.
When you go back to the path, you're completly turned around and you have no clue where your family went.\n
""")
print ("When you return to the path, it splits! Which way do you go " + name + "?")
os.system("clear")

while response not in directions:
  response = raw_input("\nleft/right/backwards\n")
  if response == "left":
        print("You head down the left path. The night is getting darker...")
      elif response == "right":
        print("You head down the right path. The night is getting darker...")
    elif response == "backwards":
        print("You head down the path behind you. You start to see a faint light. As you get closer, you see your family's RV!")
    else: 
        print("Please type one of the following: left/right/backwards.")```
````

Comment: Please post your code in the question.  Posting it as a link makes it harder for us to help.

Comment: Well, do you know what the word `indentation` means? If you do: do you understand why it's important in Python? Do you know how to figure out how much indentation there should be? Is there the correct amount of indentation? If not: please use a dictionary and look it up, then go to the other steps. "Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?" isn't a question we can help you with, because the error message already told you **exactly** what's wrong with the code, so there isn't a way to know what else to tell you.

Comment: Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and note that you are expected to put your code *in the question itself*.

Comment: Line up all your elif statements with the first if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an `if-else` statement, all of the `if`, `elif`, and `else` words need to be indented to the same number of spaces.

Your code currently looks like:

```
  if response == "left":
        print("You head down the left path. The night is getting darker...")
      elif response == "right":
        print("You head down the right path. The night is getting darker...")
    elif response == "backwards":
        print("You head down the path behind you. You start to see a faint light. As you get closer, you see your family's RV!")
    else: 
        print("Please type one of the following: left/right/backwards.")
```

Notice how the first `elif` is many spaces in from the `if` and also the the following `else` and `elif`.

Make sure they are all indented the same amount:

```
  if response == "left":
        print("You head down the left path. The night is getting darker...")
  elif response == "right":
        print("You head down the right path. The night is getting darker...")
  elif response == "backwards":
        print("You head down the path behind you. You start to see a faint light. As you get closer, you see your family's RV!")
  else: 
        print("Please type one of the following: left/right/backwards.")
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently still learning how to Python and I didn't know that everything had to be indented the same.

Comment: "I didn't know that everything had to be indented the same." - Please tell us what source you are using to learn Python, so I can make sure not to recommend it to anyone. This is just about the first thing that any tutorial should tell you.

Answer (score -1):

if/elif/else statements must all be indented to the same depth:

```
if x == 1:
    do_something()

elif x == 2:
    do_something_else()

elif x == 3:
    do_this()

else:
    do_that()
```